# Trouble accessing json properties in Jinja2 template

Tags: json, pandas, flask, jinja2

I've searched around but the answers I've found aren't working for some reason.

I'm building a flask web app. I load a csv into a dataframe and display it in a table on a page (index). You can click a button to select a row and the row's details will populate below the table.

Everything works and I can print the json object returned when a row is selected, but can't print any of the properties.

I've tried `row.first`, `row['first']`, `row.first[0]`, and other various arrangements.

What am I doing wrong / what is the proper way to interact with json objects in Jinja2?

Json from single row that is correctly returned to the template

```
{
  "seq": {
    "0": 1
  },
  "first": {
    "0": "Justin"
  },
  "last": {
    "0": "Powell"
  },
  "state": {
    "0": "ND"
  },
  "email": {
    "0": "idomapsok@bu.ne"
  }
}
```

`views.py`

```
from flask import render_template, jsonify
from wsaflask import bp
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('wsaflask/input.csv')

@bp.route('/update-details/<int:id>', methods = ['POST'])
def update_details(id):
    row_details = data.loc[data['seq'] == id]
    return jsonify('', render_template('row-details.html', row = row_details.to_json()))

@bp.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', data = data)
```

`row-details.html`

```
<div id="detail-display">
    {% if row %}
    <!-- How to print row.first (name) here -->
    <p>{{ row }}</p>
    {% endif %}
</div>
```

`index.html`

```
<body>
    <section class="container">
      <div style="max-height: 35vh; overflow-y: scroll;">
        <table class="table">
          <tr>
            {% for col in data.columns %}
            <th>{{ col }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
            <th>
              action
            </th>
          </tr>
          {% for _, row in data.iterrows() %}
          <tr>
            {% for col in data.columns %}
            <td>{{ row[col] }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
            <td>
              <button onclick="updateDetails(row_id = {{row['seq']}})" class="btn btn-link btn-sm">Select</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          {% endfor %}
        </table>
      </div>
      <!-- Div below is replaced with row-details.html via js -->
      <div id="detail-display">
      </div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function updateDetails(row_id){
  var id = row_id
  $.ajax({
    url:"/update-details/" + id,
    type:"POST",
    dataType:"json",
    success: function(data){
      $('#detail-display').replaceWith(data)
    }

  });
}
```

Comment: hi, perhaps pass the data as an object (no need to convert it to a json string) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229486/how-to-pass-data-to-jinja-templet

Comment: You got me on on the right track, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay I figured it out, @jspcal got me looking in the right direction and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48051288/18969244).

In short, Flask's to_json() function returns a json string rather than an actual object, though they look similar.

The view to update the data now looks like this:

```
import json

@bp.route('/update-details/<int:id>', methods = ['POST'])
def update_details(id):
    row_df = data.loc[data['seq'] == id]
    row_json = row_df.to_json(orient = 'records')
    results = json.loads(row_json)
    return jsonify('', render_template('row-details.html', row = results))
```

First I added the 'orient' parameter. This changes the structure of the resulting json string. See the [docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html). It was a bit of a guessing game for me, but here's how the json looks now:

```
[
  {
    'seq': 1, 
    'first': 'Justin', 
    'last': 'Powell', 
    'state': 'ND', 
    'email': 'idomapsok@bu.ne'
  }
]
```

Then after importing json (just `import json`), load the json string using `json.loads(your_json_string)`, and pass the results to the template instead of just the string.

Now in my template, I can get the first name using `row[0].first`.

I'm not 100% sure what's happening so I'm sure this isn't the ideal way to handle this, but it gets the job done.